# Matrix $A$ has random integer entries. Probability to get a matrix of integer elements after $A$ has been echelon row reduced?

Tags: probability, matrices, random-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix with integer elements uniformly randomly chosen between $-k$ and $k$. What is the probability to get a matrix of integer elements after $A$ has been reduced in reduced row echelon form?

Comment: What's the relation between Hermite normal form and the row echelon form?